# React navigation icon component Animation

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation

I have a react navigation bottom navigator V3 with three tabs:

- Affiche
- ArScreen
- Settings

The middle icon must be a large icon, and when I go to the corresponding screen, I need to run an animation on this icon. The animation is based on Gooey effect like here:

https://itnext.io/react-native-tab-bar-is-customizable-c3c37dcf711f

So my question is:

I found how to add this component ICON to my tab bar like this:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
 Affiche: {
  screen: Affiche,
 },
 ArScreen: {
  screen: ArScreen,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarIcon: (<AddButton/>),
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => {
      this.child.handleAddButtonPressOpen();
      navigation.navigate('ArScreen');
    }
 })
},
 Settings: {
  screen: Settings,
 }
});
```

and my AddButton component got a function that enable animation:

```
handleAddButtonPressOpenClose = () => {
     let { pressed } = this.state;
     if(pressed) {
         this.animateReverse(0);
     }
     else {

             this.animate(1);
     }
     this.setState({pressed: !pressed});
 }
```

So when I press in my middle button, I want the navigation to go to the Screen ArScreen and also run the AddButton animation. Actually I cannot get the two to run together.

Comment: Can you run animation separately?

Comment: Yes If I trigger onPress inside AddButton component TouchableOpacity button It works and If I trigger this.props.navigation.navigate("ArScreen") It works but I try to run it synchronously like the tab press active the screen and in the same time the animation run.It's like this.props.navigation.navigate("ArScreen") interrupt my animation.